# Is there a template for settings.json in vscode for accessing marketplace from behind a proxy?

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings, http-proxy

I installed vscode recently in a system (Windows 10 OS) at my office and found out that marketplace is not accessible inside vscode because of which I am unable to add useful extensions to the ide (example angular essentials for V9 by John Papa). I added the proxy url from vscode settings -> Application Proxy, added HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY environment variables also but I don't know how to add the username/password to the settings.xml that is created under %User%AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json. Currently the settings.json has the following content:

```
{
  "http.proxy": <myorgproxy>,
  "timeline.pageSize": 0,
  "http.proxyAuthorization": null
}
```

I am not sure whether the proxy is not working because of the last entry in the settings.json. The user manual in vscode official site states that the settings are similar to chromium but the target page given as reference also is not useful for me as I am pretty new to it. Any leads/hints to solve this will be highly appreciated.

Edit: as of now, the logs show this error while trying to connect to marketplace:

```
[2020-05-13 14:37:59.255] [renderer3] [error] net::ERR_NO_SUPPORTED_PROXIES: Error: net::ERR_NO_SUPPORTED_PROXIES
    at SimpleURLLoaderWrapper.<anonymous> (electron/js2c/browser_init.js:2623:21)​
    at SimpleURLLoaderWrapper.emit (events.js:203:13)
```

Comment: The value to set is the `Proxy-Authorization` header to send with each request. Ask your sysadmin what the format is of this string

Comment: @rioV8 thank you for that suggestion. So, once I add the proxy-authorization, will that start working or do I need to add more values to the settings.json?

Comment: The definition of `http.proxyAuthorization` has the type `type:["null","string"]`. Or you can add it to the proxy setting like https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-set-proxy-environment-variable/